# Updating record based on the value in variable in WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm tring to execute this query and getting error code: 1175 use are using safe mode and you tried to update table without where clause.

this is the query

```
set @email = 'foo@bar.com';
UPDATE user SET date_of_birth = '1985-10-01' 
WHERE email_id = @email;
```

I don't want to disable safe mode.

Comment: use the PK in the where clause

Comment: are you trying it on workbench ?

Comment: Yes, use PK in where clause

Comment: Yes @AbdulrehmanSheikh

Comment: have you tried to use PK in where clause ?

Comment: i can't use @AbdulrehmanSheikh

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't want to disable the safe mode in MySQL Workbench, you may want to tweak your query so you can use the primary key in the where clause.

```
set @email = 'foo@bar.com';
set @id =
(
    SELECT u.id
    FROM user u
    WHERE u.email_id = @email
);

UPDATE user SET date_of_birth = '1985-10-01' 
WHERE id = @id;
```

Or directly :

```
SET @id = 42;

UPDATE user SET date_of_birth = '1985-10-01' 
WHERE id = @id;
```

Or, disable the safe mode temporary (this is the option I'll choose) :

```
set @email = 'foo@bar.com';

SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0;

UPDATE user SET date_of_birth = '1985-10-01' 
WHERE email_id = @email;

SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 1;
```

Comment: if i use the second solution this what i'm getting in back Error Code: 1093. You can't specify target table 'user' for update in FROM clause

Comment: @RajatVerma I changed the first query